# Angularjs update other fields when one change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I rewrote the question.

My data is a list of objects, lets say rows. For every row I build an excel-like table of cells, this way

```
<div ng-repeat="row in dataRows">
   <input ng-model="row.a"><input ng-model="row.b">{{row.c}}
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is an automatic update of `c` field based on changes of `a` and `b`.
I tried to use `$scope.$watch` but this monitor my whole dataRows and I would like to fire a calculating value of `c` for those rows which changed

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand nothing. Please post clear example,; expected and actual results/behavior

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<div ng-repeat="row in dataRows">
  <input ng-model="row.a" ng-change="update($index)"><input ng-model="row.b" ng-change="update($index)">{{row.c}}
</div>

$scope.update = function(index) {
  var row = $scope.dataRows(index);
  row.c = row.a + row.b // or whatever
}
```